# Sharing settings across methods in namespaced jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm writing a plugin and following the jQuery documentation's recommended practice http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring when it comes to namespacing and multiple methods.

My init() takes care of merging default and custom settings using $.extend() however I can not figure out how to make those options available outside of the init() method. Say that call and initialize my plugin using

```
$("a").myplugin({debug:false});
```

how can I reference the debug property later when I call

```
$("a").myplugin("someMethod")?
```

A rough example is:

```
   (function( $ ){
        var methods = {
            init: function(customSettings) {
                var options = {
                    debug: true
                }
                return this.each(function () {
                   if (customSettings) {
                       $.extend(options, customSettings);
                   }
                });
            },
            someMethod: function() {
               if(options.debug) { // <-- How can I access options here?
                   // do something
               }
            }
         }
    })( jQuery );

    $.fn.myplugin = function (method) {
                if (methods[method]) {
                    return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                }
                else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                     return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                else {
                     $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tbwaga');
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 7):

I didn't look at your plugin template, but I wanted to share this [jQuery plugin formatting](http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/)... it adds a reverse reference to the DOM object in jQuery's stored data. This makes it very easy to access the plugin functions and/or variables even from outside of the plugin closure.

Here is a [post](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/) describing the plugin structure in more detail.

So to access a function inside the plugin, you simply use the data object:

```
$('a').data('myplugin').function_name();
```

or even get a variable from the plugin settings

```
var height = $('a').data('myplugin').options.height;
```

---

But to answer your question, to make your options available to other functions inside the closure, just define the option variable outside of the init function:

```
(function( $ ){
        var options, methods = {
            init: function(customSettings) {
                options = {
                    debug: true
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [fudgy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145346/fudgey) wrote you may consider setting your defaults outside the init method. 
I tried following that same tutorial and came up with the following code combining settings and methods, but I ran into some other disadvantage.

```
  (function( $ ){
     var config, methods = {
        init: function(customSettings) {
            var config = {
                debug: true
            }
            return this.each(function () {
               if (customSettings) {
                   $.extend(config, customSettings);
               }
            });
        },
        someMethod: function(arg) {
           if(options.debug) {
               // do something
               alert('debug ' + arg);
           } else {
               alert('no debug' + arg);
           }
        }
    }

    $.fn.myplugin = function (method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myplugin' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

But when your call it like:

```
$('p.one').myplugin({ 'debug' : 'false' });
```

For the second paragraph debug is unfortunately still false.

```
$('p.two').myplugin('someMethod', 'hmm!');
```

I first need to init the paragraph with 'true' again to be able to debug it.

```
$('p.two').myplugin({ 'debug' : 'true' });
$('p.two').myplugin('someMethod', 'hmm!');
```

Did I oversee something in the tutorial?

Comment: Don't extend the options itself, extend to an empty object: `$.extend({}, options, customSettings);`

Comment: Also, you need to store the options (reverse reference to the DOM as mentioned in the post I linked) so your methods can access them.

Comment: @fudgey I think I've nailed it thanks to your help! I've edited and replacied the above code sample with your remarks.